# swagger-codegen 3 python not working with Authorization

Tags: python, swagger-codegen, urllib3

```
# Configure API key authorization: sso_auth
# configuration = pingdom_client.Configuration()
# configuration.api_key = {
#     'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'}
# configuration.api_key_prefix['Authorization'] = 'Bearer'
# handle = pingdom_client.ApiClient(header_name='Authorization',
#                                   header_value='Bearer <token>')
# api_instance = pingdom_client.MarketApi(pingdom_client.ApiClient(configuration))
handle = pingdom_client.ApiClient(header_name='Authorization',
                                  header_value='Bearer <token>')

check = pingdom_client.ChecksApi(api_client=handle)
thread = check.checks_get_with_http_info(async_req=True)
result = thread.get()
print(result)
```

I was trying to use pingdom api using swagger. and it is not working.